# Select value with Linux command xpath (from Perl)

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I want to get an attribute out of a XML-Tree. Therefor I use the command xpath from package libxml-xpath-perl. I figured out this command:

```
virsh dumpxml save | xpath -e "/domain/devices/disk[@type='file']/source/@file[1]"
```

This gives me

```
 file="/var/lib/libvirt/images/save.raw"
```

How can I select the value only? (/var/lib/libvirt/images/save.raw)

Thanks

falstaff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use (maybe because I wrote it ;--) `xml_grep2`, from [App::xml_grep2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-xml_grep2), which has a convenient `-t` option that returns the text value of the result:

```
virsh dumpxml save | xml_grep2 -t "/domain/devices/disk[@type='file']/source/@file[1]"
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

You want to separate the string based on the `=`, so use `split` ([perldoc -f split](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-XPath/)):

```
my ($attr, $value) = split /=/, 'file="/var/lib/libvirt/images/save.raw"';
```

However, instead of parsing these values literally, you should use the many libraries of XML parsers, such as [XML::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-XPath/).

Comment: Its the workaround I use now in my bashscript, splitting it litterally by using cut -d = -f 2, but i want to use the xpath function for it, something like 

$ virsh dumpxml save 2>/dev/null | xpath -e "value(/domain/devices/disk[@type='file']/source/@file[1])"
...

Answer (score 0):

```
/domain/devices/disk[@type='file']/source/@file[1]/text()
```

Comment: This gives me:
$ virsh dumpxml save 2>/dev/null | xpath -e "/domain/devices/disk[@type='file']/source/@file[1]/text()"
No nodes found in stdin

Comment: Hm, obviously naked text nodes cannot be processed/displayed. It was just a guess on my part, admittedly.

Answer (score 0):

I think returning only the value is normal behaviour. Maybe it is a bug? I tried `/text()` like Tomalak suggested and it returns nothing (at least with this tool).
You could now pipe the output in another command like `sed` to get the desired result:

```
... | sed -r 's/.*?"(.*)"/\1/'
```

**Edit:**
Apparently the perl script uses `XML::XPath` and uses only `find` for the query which returns a NodeSet object. But there also is `findvalue` which the script doesn't use. Maybe you could fiddle around a little with the script. Only replacing `find` with `findvalue` gives just the value on stdout, but also error messages on stderr.
Doc for the library: https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath

Comment: Yeah its somewhat like I use now... I just would like to do it in the xpath way...

      cut -d = -f 2